# Use the output of first reader in the second reader

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm using a reader to get a stored `RequestDto` in the context:

```java
public class ItemReaderStoredData implements ItemReader<List<RequestDto>> {
    private List<RequestDto> requestListDto = new ArrayList<>();
 
    @BeforeStep
    public void retrieveInterStepData(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
        this.requestListDto = (List<RequestDto>)jobContext.get("directRequestListDto");
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<RequestDto> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        return requestListDto;
    }
}
```

I want to check the presence of each of the `uuid` of the `RequestDto` list in the database by adapting `cursorItemReader`, used in the `stepConfig`. The purpose is to write the non redundant item in a file.

```java
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<HistoricDto> cursorItemReader() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<HistoricDto> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader();
    reader.setSql("select * from tab");
    reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    reader.setRowMapper(new TableMapperDto());
    return reader;
}
```

How can I use the output of reader one in reader two, in the same step? Or is it possible to merge both code in one separate class?

**Edit:** I'm thinking to merge both: putting `JdbcCursorItemReader` in a separate class with the `@BeforeStep` of the `ItemReaderStoredData` would solve my problem. But I have issue with `Datasource` `Error` which is `Null`. Is merging them in this way safe and how to do this?

Comment: `How can I use the output of reader one in reader two, in the same step?`: A chunk-oriented step has only one reader. `The purpose is to write the non redundant item in a file.`: What are you trying to achieve? Can you explain the input/output of your job without referring to spring batch terms?

Comment: Hi, I want to read  xlsx file (input), populate a DTO, Check redunduncy in the database, filter my DTO List, Write in a a file1 new item (or database) and log redundant Item in a file2'(output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to store lists of items in the execution context as it is persisted at chunk/step boundaries (and this might be expensive in terms of performance).

> I want to read xlsx file (input), populate a DTO, Check redunduncy in the database, filter my DTO List, Write in a a file1 new item (or database) and log redundant Item in a file2'(output).

There are several ways to implement this *without* having to store items in a list and share them through the execution context. Here are a few options:

- Option 1: use an item processor to filter out existing items. Existing items can be written to file2 using a `ItemProcessListener`. Non existing items will not be filtered by the processor and can be written to the db using the step's item writer.
- Option 2: Same as option 1 but with a `SkipListener` instead of a `ItemProcessListener`. In this case, the processor would throw an exception for existing items (which should be declared as skippable) instead of returning `null` for existing items (ie filter them).
- Option 3: use an item processor to do the check and flag items as existent or not. A `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` can then be used to classify items and write them where appropriate.

There are other techniques like loading the file in a staging table and do the comparison between both tables, but those depend on the use case (input size, comparison logic, etc).

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Still that i'm supposed to read two differents sources. If I want to do all this in one step, and one step include only a reader. The first is to read the xlsx. The second is to access database. Should I include the second in an ItemProcessor  ?

Comment: You only need a single chunk-oriented step: the reader reads the xlsx file, the processor does the query to the db to check the existence of the current item (it can use a `jdbcTemplate` for example) and the writer (and/or listener depending on the approach) to write items.

Comment: If you don't want to issue a query from your processor and have an equivalent REST endpoint for that, then it's fine to replace the usage of jdbcTemplate with a REST call. If the answer helped, please accept it.